# How to perform join with multiple columns using db_select?

Tags: database

How to perform join with multiple columns using db_select? Any help?

Here below is the sample, which I'm looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM digitaliq_flds_by_node a
JOIN digitaliq_fld_category b ON
  a.fld_id = b.fld_id AND
  a.fld_collection_id = b.fld_collection_id AND
  a.fld_group_name = b.fld_group_name
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```php
$query = db_select('digitaliq_flds_by_node', 'a')->fields('a');
$alias = $query->join('digitaliq_fld_category', 'b', 'a.fld_id = %alias.fld_id AND a.fld_collection_id = %alias.fld_collection_id AND a.fld_group_name = %alias.fld_group_name');
$terms = $query->execute();
```

Calls to [`SelectQuery::join()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::join/7) (like [`SelectQuery::leftJoin()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::leftJoin/7), [`SelectQuery::innerJoin()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::innerJoin/7), and [`SelectQuery::addJoin()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::addJoin/7)) aren't chain-able because those methods don't return a `SelectQuery` object, but the actual alias used for the join. If you execute the following code, you would get an error.

```php
$query = db_select('digitaliq_flds_by_node', 'a')
  ->fields('a')
  ->join('digitaliq_fld_category', 'b', 'a.fld_id = %alias.fld_id AND a.fld_collection_id = %alias.fld_collection_id AND a.fld_group_name = %alias.fld_group_name')
  ->execute();
```

Strings in PHP are not objects nor they define an `execute()` method.

To verify the code is executing the right SQL query, cast `$query` to a string, and print it. You will get the SQL query that would be executed from your code.

```php
$query = db_select('digitaliq_flds_by_node', 'a')->fields('a');
$alias = $query->join('digitaliq_fld_category', 'b', 'a.fld_id = %alias.fld_id AND a.fld_collection_id = %alias.fld_collection_id AND a.fld_group_name = %alias.fld_group_name');
print $query;
```

With that code, I get the following output.

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM 
{digitaliq_flds_by_node} a
INNER JOIN {digitaliq_fld_category} b ON a.fld_id = b.fld_id AND a.fld_collection_id = b.fld_collection_id AND a.fld_group_name = b.fld_group_name
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$query = db_select('digitaliq_flds_by_node', 'a');
$query->join('digitaliq_fld_category', 'b', 'a.fld_id = b.fld_id');
$query->condition('a.fld_collection_id', 'b.fld_collection_id' '=');
$query->condition('a.fld_group_name', 'b.fld_group_name', '=');
$query->fields('a');
$query->execute();
```

Comment: The code you are using doesn't work: `leftJoin()` doesn't return a `SelectQuery` object. The code is calling `condition()` for something that is not an object.

Comment: In other words join is not chain able

Comment: @Mathankumar That is the word I was looking for: chain-able calls. `:)`

Comment: Still the answer is incorrect. check the answer by kiamlaluno

Comment: Now its fine. Additional note, by default the operator for condition is equal to(=), so its not necessary to specify them.