# Why is this db_select not working?

Tags: 7, database

I can't seem to figure out, are you not allowed to chain db_select methods?

```
$nid = db_select("node", "n")
            ->fields("n", array("nid"))
            ->condition("f.entity_type", "node", "=")
            ->condition("f.deleted", 0, "=")
            ->condition("f.field_products_product_id", $entity->product_id, "=")
            ->addTag("node_access")
            ->join(
                "field_data_field_products",
                "f",
                "f.entity_id = n.nid"
            )
            ->execute();
```

I have the above, and it just won't work it keeps erroring on the join. Basically I want to do

```
SELECT nid FROM node JOIN field_data_field_products ON entity_id = nid WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered in this other question:

[How to perform join with multiple columns using db_select?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53629/how-to-perform-join-with-multiple-columns-using-db-select)

> Calls to SelectQuery::join() (like-wise SelectQuery::leftJoin(),
>   SelectQuery::innerJoin(), and SelectQuery::addJoin()) chain-able
>   because those methods don't return a SelectQuery object, but the
>   actual alias used for the join.